# Error in SQL - This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression

Tags: sql, sql-update, subquery

I am trying to update a field based on two conditions

```
UPDATE TABLE1 SET FIELD1 = (SELECT SUBSTRING(LEFT(FIELD2,3),2,2) FROM TABLE1) WHERE FIELD2 LIKE '0%' AND FIELD3 IN ('OK','YES')
UPDATE TABLE1 SET FIELD1 = (SELECT SUBSTRING(LEFT(FIELD2,3),1,2) FROM TABLE1) WHERE FIELD2 NOT LIKE '0%' AND FIELD3 IN ('OK','YES')
```

Field1 has numbers that begin with 0 and 1.
If it begins with 0 then updates the first query.
If 1 then second query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the subqueries.  All you need is:

```
UPDATE TABLE1 
SET FIELD1 = SUBSTRING(LEFT(FIELD2,3),2,2) 
WHERE FIELD2 LIKE '0%' 
AND FIELD3 IN ('OK','YES')
```